# Remove lines from a file where they are present in another file 2 or more times

Tags: shell, unix, text-files

Say there are two files File1.txt and File2.txt each file contains email addresses. I need to remove all the email addresses from file1.txt if the are present in file2.txt >=2 times.

I need to do this to make sure someone isn't emailed more than two times.

I've seen other people use comm or diff for similar questions, but I'm not sure what to do in this case.

Example

```
File1.txt:  
abc@gmail.com  
def@gmail.com  
ghi@gmai.com  
jkl@gmail.com  

File2.txt:   
abc@gmail.com  
abc@gmail.com  
acb@gmai.com  
ghi@gmai.com  
jkl@gmail.com
```

Output (Files from file1 that aren't in file2.txt more than 2 times)

```
File3.txt:   
def@gmail.com  
ghi@gmai.com  
jkl@gmail.com
```

Also assume this file is 100,000+ records so it can't be done manually

Comment: Show ome sample data with related expected output. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

More or less brute force this. Assuming `File2.txt` isn't very big (i.e., can more or less fit entirely in memory), you can just go through it, count the occurrences of each line, and then use that to determine whether to print the line from `File1.txt`.

```
perl -nle 'BEGIN{open $f2, "<", "File2.txt" or die $!; while(<$f2>){$seen{$_}++}} print unless $seen{$_} > 2' File1.txt
```

This will produce the stripped version of `File1.txt` on stdout, and you can redirect it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Order `File2.txt`, and for every entry which is duplicate, verify if it's present in `File1.txt`. (`uniq -c` might come in handy)

Answer (score 0):

With `uniq` you can find lines that are repeated:

```
sort File2.txt | uniq -d
```

These are the lines you want to remove from `File1.txt`.
When the `uniq` output is in a file, you can use this file for a `grep` statement.

```
sort File2.txt | uniq -d > /tmp/derek.tmp
grep -vf /tmp/derek.tmp File1.txt
```

These lines can be combined into

```
grep -vf <(sort File2.txt | uniq -d) File1.txt
```